# Applets illustrating the operation of diodes and transistors

Tags: transistors, diodes

Anyone know a site with interactive applets illustrating the operation of diodes and transistors as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Falstad](http://falstad.com/circuit/) is a simple Java simulator with the basic components, and some demos about diodes, like [this](http://falstad.com/circuit/#$+1+5.0E-6+10.634267539816555+50+2.0+50%0AR+336+192+336+144+0+3+50.0+0.65+0.25+0.0+0.5%0Ad+336+192+336+272+1+0.805904783%0Ag+336+272+336+304+0%0Ao+1+64+0+34+1.25+25.6+0+-1%0Ao+1+64+0+33+0.625+51.2+0+-1%0Ao+1+64+0+99+1.25+51.2+1+-1+I+vs+V%0A), and transistors, like [this](http://falstad.com/circuit/#$+1+5.0E-6+10.634267539816555+43+2.0+50%0A172+288+240+256+240+0+6+0.7025+0.75+0.5+0.0+0.5+Base+Voltage%0Aw+400+256+400+304+1%0Aw+400+224+400+176+1%0A172+400+176+400+144+0+6+2.0+2.0+0.0+0.0+0.5+Collector+Voltage%0Ag+400+304+400+320+0%0At+352+240+400+240+0+1+-1.2974999999999999+0.7025+100.0%0Aw+288+240+352+240+1%0A). It may not be the most beautiful or most complete, but it's quite intuitive to use.

Take a look, but I would suggest you to try matching the examples with the theory, to understand better what is the *transconductance* \$ \beta _F\$ and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a really good series of videos on transistors: [one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CkX8SkTgB0g) and [two](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4QkRI1Ue208&feature=related). [This](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cyhzpFqXwdA&feature=results_video&playnext=1&list=PL765189B018D815E1) next video is on diodes and rectification but you you should definitely check how his whole electronics series.

Comment: OP wants an applet, not videos. I guess he needs something interactive.